# Assignment makes pointer from Integer without a Cast in Structure

Tags: c, list, pointers, dynamic, struct

I'm making a program that dynamically creates a list of integers.

```
int ins_dlist(int data, struct dlist **p){
struct dlist *q;

if((*p)->sz == (*p)->maxsz){
    q = realloc(*p, DLISTSZ((*p)->maxsz + INCRSZ));
    if(q == NULL)
        return (-1);
    q->maxsz += INCRSZ;
    *p = q;
}

//(*p)->item[(*p)->sz++] = data; <-Gives me pointer from integer without cast
*((*p)->item + (*p)->sz++) = data;
return(0);

}
```

My problem is on `*((*p)->item + (*p)->sz++) = data;` I tried declaring it in different ways but I still can't get access to the `sz` variable in my struct. 
Heres my struct declaration, its inside a file named dlist.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct dlist{
     int sz;
    int maxsz;
    int *item[1];
};

#define INITSZ 5
#define INCRSZ 5
#define DLISTSZ(n) ((size_t)(sizeof(struct dlist)) + ((n-1)*sizeof(int)))

struct dlist *init_dlist(int num);
int ins_dlist(int data, struct dlist **p);
```

Comment: Review your declaration of `struct dlist` or post it here.

Comment: I declared it in a file called dlist.h, edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to define `dllist` as:

```
struct dlist{
   int sz;
   int maxsz;
   int item[1];
};
```